# How to preserve buffer local variables through `recompile`?

Tags: buffer-local

In a compilation buffer, when I set buffer local variable like so:

```
(setq-local foo 'bar)
```

Doing a `(recompile)` will unset this variable.

Is there a way to keep the buffer local value permanent through recompiles?